# Angular 6 Computed Property binding in ngFor not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple class.

```
export class TestModel {
  id: number;
  month: string;
  year: string;

  get monthYear(): string {
    return this.month + '-' + this.year;
  }
}
```

and this is populated with a typical service call to get a list of values.

```
getVehicleMonths(): Observable<TestModel[]> {
        return this.http.get<TestModel[]>('api/monthyears')
                   .pipe(map(data => data['results']));
    }
```

My component is fetching the list OK.

In the Html, I want to show the computed property like this syntax but nothing is shown.

```
<mat-select formControlName="vehicleMonthId" (selectionChange)="onValueChanged($event)" aria-required="false">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let c of monthsAndYears" [value]="c.id">{{c.monthYear}} 
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

I know I can do {{c.month}} - {{c.year}}, but how do I get computed fields to work?

Or is there the MobX approach (like Vue.js Aurelia.io) and can get this to work with a @computed attribute?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have any error message in the console  ?

Comment: Make the getter monthYear (explicitly) public?

Comment: I would expect an error when trying to map to a class with a `get` method...How is "fetching the list ok"? How does `data['results']` look like?

Comment: Even if you declared your TestModel class, in ngFor it does not know that `c` is an actual instance of that class. You have to map all objects in monthsAndYears and do a `new TestModel` for each one of them. rst kind of explains this in the answer below

Comment: Codes working fine fetching.  If I bind and show {{c.month}} the dropdown is populated.  Just want it working with a computed field if this is possible - it appears my understanding of when the computed field is evaluated is my question.

Comment: @richardb - The answer by @rst should solve your problem. You have to call the constructor to get a valid `TestModel` object.

Comment: @richardb: please replace you code at the mapping line by this and show us the output: `.pipe(map(data => { console.log(data['results']); data['results']; }));`, I don't believe the fetching works properly

Comment: @richardb: So what is the status? No upvotes, no accepted answer, no futher comments...

Comment: In the end I did <mat-option *ngFor="let c of vehicleMonths" [value]="c.id">{{c.month}}-{{c.year}}</mat-option>...... I could also do this.vehicleMonthService.getVehicleMonths().subscribe(data => {
   this.vehicleMonths = data;
   this.vehicleMonths.forEach(x => x.monthYear = x.month + '-' + x.year);
  });

Answer (score 0):

Your code shouldn't work in the first place. You can't just map to a class with functions. If you have a proper constructor e.g. then the `get` method will work properly

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Testmodel {
  a: string;
  b: string;

  get ab(): string {
    return this.a+'-'+this.b;
  }

  constructor(a: string, b: string) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

  /*
       Alternatively, if you have a complex constructor, you could do something like 
  constructor(options: {'a': string, 'b': string}) {
    this.a = options.a;
    this.b = options.b;
  }

  and then in the mapper just 
     result => new Testmodel(result)
  */ 
}

@Component({
  template: `<div *ngFor="let c of y">{{c.ab}}</div>`,
  styleUrls: [],
  selector: 'app-list'
})
export class Blub {
  x = [{'a': 'Hallo', 'b': 'World'}, {'a': 'Foo', 'b': 'Bar'}];
  y: Testmodel[];

  constructor() {
    this.y = this.x.map(a => new Testmodel(a.a, a.b));
  }
}
```

> Yields:
>
> Hallo-World
>
> Foo-Bar

Comment: To simplify your code, use `constructor(public a: string, public b: string) { }`.